# Dropped hard drive won't mount

Tags: macos, mac, data-recovery

I have a 2 TB HFS+-formatted external hard drive that got dropped a couple of days ago while transferring files onto a Macbook Pro.  Now the drive's partitions won't mount.  Disk Utility can see the drive, but doesn't recognize that it has any partitions.

I've tried using [Data Rescue 2](http://prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php) to recover files off of it, but it couldn't find anything.  In addition, our local computer repair shop said they couldn't find anything on there either.

I know that I could ship the drive off to someone like [DriveSavers](http://www.drivesaversdatarecovery.com/), but I was hoping for a cheaper option (since they start at about $500 for the attempt).

Is there something else I could try on my own?  Would [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) be able to help with something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its best if you let the professionals handle the hd, you wouldn't want to screw up such a lovely piece of tech :)

Answer (score 0):

Give [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) a try. There's a bunch of [testimonials](http://www.grc.com/sr/testimonials.htm) -- take them as you will.

It's not free and you'll need to mount the drive in PC hardware.

Can you hear the drive spin up?